# Why do I get nonstandard responses from the TPM Through TBS?

Tags: tpm, trusted-computing

I have a C++ program to do a basic TPM_GetCapabilities Through TPM Base Services and the Windows 7 SDK.

I've setup the program below

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{       
    TBS_CONTEXT_PARAMS    pContextParams;
    TBS_HCONTEXT        hContext;
    TBS_RESULT            rv;
    pContextParams.version = TBS_CONTEXT_VERSION_ONE;
    rv = Tbsi_Context_Create(&pContextParams, &hContext);
    printf("\n1 RESULT : %x  STATUS : %x", rv, hContext);   
    BYTE data[200] =   
       {0,0xc1,     /* TPM_TAG_RQU_COMMAND */
        0,0,0,18,  /* blob length, bytes */
        0,0,0,0x65, /* TPM_ORD_GetCapability */
        0,0,0,0x06,   /* TPM_CAP_VERSION */
        0,0,0,0}; /* 0 bytes subcap */


    BYTE buf[4000];
    UINT32 len = 4000;    

    rv = Tbsip_Submit_Command(hContext,0,TBS_COMMAND_PRIORITY_NORMAL,data,18,buf,&len); 
    //CAPABILITY_RETURN* retVal = new CAPABILITY_RETURN(buf);
    //printf("\n2 Response Tag: %x Output Bytes: %x",tag,);
    printf("\n2 RESULT : %x  STATUS : %x\n", rv, hContext);
    printBuf(buf,len);  
    rv = Tbsip_Context_Close(hContext);
    printf("\n3 RESULT : %x  STATUS : %x", rv, hContext);
```

My Return Buffer looks like:

```
00:C4:00:00:00:12:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:04:01:01:00:00
```

According to this doc, Section 7.1 TPM_GetCapability I should get the following:
[image]

Looking at my output buffer, I am getting TPM_TAG_RSP_COMMAND,a value of 18 for my paramSize, 0 for my TPM_RESULT, 0x...04 for ordinal (Not sure what this is supposed to mean.) then 1,1,0,0 for my final bits. I'm at a loss as to how to decipher this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The answer to your question:

You don't get a *nonstandard* response.

1. The response is perfectly fine, there is nothing *nonstandard* in it. It looks exactly like it is defined in the spec.
2. The response' content `resp` you get is also what is to be expected. A Standard conform TPM has to answer with `01 01 00 00` when asked for `TPM_CAP_VERSION`.

## Why?

First of all: The line stating `TPM_COMMAND_CODE ordinal` is **not** part of the response.
It has no `PARAM #` and no `PARAM SZ`. It is only relevant for calculating the HMAC of the response.

So the response is the following:

```
00 C4          tag
00 00 00 12    paramSize
00 00 00 00    returnCode
00 00 00 04    respSize
01 01 00 00    resp
```

You asked for the capability `TPM_CAP_VERSION`. Here is what the spec says:

```
Value:             0x00000006
Capability Name:   TPM_CAP_VERSION
Sub cap:           Ignored

TPM_STRUCT_VER structure.
The major and minor version MUST indicate 1.1.
The firmware revision MUST indicate 0.0.

The use of this value is deprecated, new software SHOULD
use TPM_CAP_VERSION_VAL to obtain version and revision information
regarding the TPM.
```

So when you decode `resp`, which is a `TPM_STRUCT_VER`, you get the following:

```
typedef struct tdTPM_STRUCT_VER {
    BYTE major;      // ==> 1
    BYTE minor;      // ==> 1
    BYTE revMajor;   // ==> 0
    BYTE revMinor;   // ==> 0
} TPM_STRUCT_VER;
```

So 1.1 and 0.0, exactly according to specification.

Comment: Well, consider me educated. Thanks.